# Proving a set is a subset of another

Tags: elementary-set-theory

While reading a prove regarding transitive closure, I have problem in explaining the statement below in formal proof:

To show that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}R^n \subseteq T$, it suffices to show that for all $n\in \mathbb N, R^n \subseteq T$.

Intuitively I understand it because $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N}R^n$ means $R\cup R^1 \cup R^2... \cup R^n$, so if I can show that for all $n \in \mathbb N, R^n \subseteq T$, then surely $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N}R^n \subseteq T$. But how should I put it in right word?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Proposition.** Let $Y$ denote a subset of a larger set $\Omega$, and suppose $X_{i \in I}$ is a family of subsets of $\Omega$. Then

$$\forall i \in I(X_i⊆Y) \iff (\cup i \in I : X_i) \subseteq Y$$

*Proof.*

$(\Rightarrow).$ Assume $\; \forall i \in I(X_i⊆Y).$ We will show $(\cup i∈I : X_i) \subseteq Y$

Now let $x \in (\cup i∈I : X_i).$ We will show $x \in Y.$ By hypothesis, we can find $j \in I$ with $x \in X_j$. Fix any such $i \in I$. Then $X_i \subseteq Y.$ So $x \in Y$.

$(\Leftarrow).$ Assume $(\cup i∈I : X_i) \subseteq Y.$ We will show $\; \forall i \in I(X_i⊆Y).$

Let $j \in I$ be fixed but arbitary. We will show $X_j \subseteq Y$. We by Lemma 1 (which is yet to be proved) have that $X_j \subseteq (\cup i∈I : X_i) = Y.$ This completes the proof.

**Lemma 1.** Let $X_{i \in I}$ denote a family of subsets of $\Omega$. Then for any $j \in I$, we have that $X_j \subseteq (\cup i∈I : X_i).$

*Proof.* Let $j \in I$ be fixed but arbitrary. We will show $X_j \subseteq (\cup i∈I : X_i).$

Let $x \in X_j$ be fixed but arbitrary. We will show $x \in (\cup i∈I : X_i).$ This is the same as saying that there exists $i \in I$ such that $x \in X_i$. But there's an obvious choice, namely $i=j$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Does it imply that $⋃_{n∈\mathbb{N}}X_n \subseteq Y$ iff $\forall n∈\mathbb{N}(X_n⊆Y)$?

Comment: @DaveClifford, that's certainly true, although I only proved one direction.

Comment: can you prove in other direction? that is the direction I am having trouble with. Thanks.

Comment: @DaveClifford, sure I'll give it a go. No promises though.

Comment: @DaveClifford, I've done it, but not 100% satisfied with the result. To do this kind of thing properly, you have to do it right from the beginning, so you're very clear in your own head what you are and aren't allowed to take for granted.

Answer (score 0):

The set $S:=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}R^n$ has (by definition) the property that $x\in S$ implies
$$\exists n\in\mathbb N\colon x\in R^n$$
Thus for arbitrary $x\in S$, let $n_0\in \mathbb N$ be such that $x\in R^{n_0}$.
Then from $R^{n_0}\subseteq T$ we have $x\in T$. That is $x\in S$ implies $x\in T$, in other words $S\subseteq T$.

Comment: First I have to apologize because I didn't state my question clearly which results your answer doesn't quite answer my statement. What I am trying to ask is that is proving $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}R^n \subseteq T$ the same as proving for all $n\in \mathbb N, R^n \subseteq T$?